# error given Sending json array in ajax request? using javascript

Tags: ajax, json

hihi i am doing a project regarding ajax (xmlHttRequest), 
how am i going to call the title in the note session, because normally if you call start year is like, `detail = eval....
then for loop it
inside should be
var start year=""
startyear += ...[i].startyear` 
something like this, but how am i going to call the title inside the note?
 i try to call detail.notes.note.title it say is null or is not a object

this is json data:

```
{
"infos": {
    "info": [
        {
            "startYear": "1900",
            "endYear": "1930",
            "timeZoneDesc": "daweerrewereopreproewropewredfkfdufssfsfsfsfrerewrBlahhhhh..",
            "timeZoneID": "1",
            "note": {
                "notes": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "title": "Mmm"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "title": "Wmm"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "3",
                        "title": "Smm"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "links": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "Red House",
                    "url": "http://infopedia.nl.sg/articles/SIP_611_2004-12-24.html"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Joo Chiat",
                    "url": "http://www.the-inncrowd.com/joochiat.htm"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "title": "Bake",
                    "url": "https://thelongnwindingroad.wordpress.com/tag/red-house-bakery"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Woo. Punctuation, syntax and orthography could possibly make this question understandable.

Comment: @Hyperboreus do you know how to?

Comment: Your parser won't be able to read your JSON as it is not well-formed. Try to fix it and then try to parse again.

Comment: @Hyperboreus it only half of the code so how should be get the title of the note..i have change it to no error

Answer (score 0):

Use http://jsonlint.com/ to help you out with JSON.

I got this...

```
Parse error on line 30:
...         ]        }
----------------------^
Expecting '}', ',', ']'
```

Comment: change already, so do you know how should call out the title in the note session(array)

Comment: detail.notes.note.title <-- you're calling it wrong detail.infos.info.note.notes should be correct :)

Comment: i try out your then it say error ...is null or is not an object

Comment: Weird, try including http://www.json.org/json2.js this file or if you're not on IE details = JSON.parse(<the data here>); should work fine then try going about from there. What does details.infos say?

or this https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js

Comment: detail.infos work but it does not able to call the title in the note